# Using method in created hook gives reference error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm in the process of learning Vue but I'm having some (basic) issues.

I'm trying to call a method that's defined in the component, when the component renders. For that I'm using the `created` hook, but I'm getting this in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: myMethod is not defined`.

My component javascript looks like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  methods: {
    myMethod: function () {
      console.log("asd123")
    }
  },
  created: myMethod()
}
```

If it's relevant for my issue: the component in question is getting rendered through `vue-router`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the structure shown in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks):

```js
export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  methods: {
    myMethod: function () {
      console.log("asd123")
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.myMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh -- awesome. I thought I was being smart, thank you.